# How to compare a key stored in models.py with the key fetched from the POST request?

Tags: django

I want to check the validity of the consumer_key. I have stored one in the models.py as a CharField but how do I go on and fetch it for comparison ? 
This might help understand the problem better .

Models.py

```
class Verification(models.Model):
    consumer_key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hidden_key  = models.CharField(max_length=30 , default="")
```

Views.py

```
from .models import Verfication

id = Verification.objects.filter()
if request_key ==id.values('consumer_key'):
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer( key=request_key,secret= id.values('hidden_key'))
```

request_key contains the oauth_consumer_key .

Comment: Do you want to **check** whether there is a `Verification` object with the given `consumer_key` _or_ **validate** a given `consumer_key` against a single instance of `Verification`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from .models import Verfication

try:
    id = Verification.objects.get(consumer_key = request_key)
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=request_key,secret= id.hidden_key)

except Verification.DoesNotExist:
    pass   #token does not exist
```

This will try to get `Verification` object using `request_key` and call exception if `request_key` is not in database.

Also `consumer_key` should be set to unique in models using `unique=True` to prevent having multiple entries for same `consumer_key`.

Comment: This works but does this compare the form request_key with the consumer_key stored in the database ?

Comment: @ShoryaSharma it tries to get Verification object by consumer_key using request_key. So if the request_key is wrong and there is no model with this key, exception will be called and no object will be returned.